# Manda dato solo cuando lo relocalizo

Tags: javascript

tengo un link con su respectivo href que quiere enviar datos al servidor pero uso prevent para antes preguntar si estoy seguro, si le doy SI yo pensaba que deberia enviar la comunicacion con el servidor pero no hacer nada, pero si lo relocalizo funciona

```js
$(function() {
 $('.envios').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  swal({
   title: "Aviso",
   text: "Está seguro que desea salir ? ",
   icon: "warning",
   buttons: true,
   dangerMode: true,
  })
  .then((willDelete) => {
   if (willDelete) {
            //Mensaje Opcional
            swal("Usted será redireccionado", {
             icon: "success",
            });
            console.log(this.href);
            // redirección location.href = this.href
        } else {
         swal("Canceceló la acción");
        }
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<a href='envaluacion/primera' class="envios">Irse</a>
<a href='envaluacion/segunda' class="envios">Irse a Otra</a>
```

cuando uso ajax me redirecciona, pero porque y como lo arreglo?

```js
$('.btnDeletes').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var nombreEva = 'evaDinamica';
      var idSalida = this.id;
      console.log('LÑ', idSalida);

      swal({
          title: "Esta seguro de eliminar al usuario?",
          text: "Elija una opcion",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        }).then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
              $.ajax({
                url: "/evaluacion/concerderRsol/" + nombreEva + "/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                  nombreEva: nombreEva,
                  user: id
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function() {
                  console.log('success');
                  swal("si!", "bien", "success");
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  console.log('error');
                  swal("Error!", "Please try again", "error");
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<button class="btnDeletes" id="uno">enviar</button>
```

Comment: ¿Qué deseas enviar al servidor ? ¿Qué funciona y que no en su código? no logro comprender exactamente qué desea lograr.

Comment: @Dev.Joel tengo datos en el href href='envaluacion/primera' 'primera', 'segunda' son dinamicos

Comment: @Dev.Joel las palabras primera y segunda...ect son valores que quiero enviar al servidor

Comment: A que te refieres con _(debería enviar la comunicación con el servidor)_  te refieres a una petición Ajax?  no veo donde hace la comunicación con el servidor, solo se ve una posible re dirección comentada. Podría explicar mejor que desea lograr, en particular yo, no entiendo muy bien aún.

Comment: @Dev.Joel cuando le doy click en el link el servidor debe oirle mediante get o es necesario usar ajax?

Comment: Si desea enviar datos por get sin recargar la página, Sí, hace falta una petición ajax. cuando realiza el click en ningún lugar de su código hace la comunicación con el servidor,

Comment: @Dev.Joel en este caso necesito que envie los datos sin ajax

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81676/discussion-between-dev-joel-and-hubman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yo pensaba que debería enviar la comunicación con el servidor pero no
>   hacer nada

No, al hacer `click`  una forma de que se produzca la petición sería, mediante la redirección, O a través de `Ajax`  para no tener que recargar la página.*(está petición hacía falta en su primera porción de código)*

Para el segundo ejemplo,Como mencioné, el error es simple y básicamente es un error de sintaxis, ya que hace falta el cierre del `then` con el paréntesis  `)`,  además de recomendar utilizar done para la devolución de éxito de las peticiones `Ajax`.

Posible código final

```
$('.btnDeletes').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombreEva = 'evaDinamica';
    var idSalida = this.id;
    let id = 12; // valor de prueba
    swal({
      title: "Esta seguro de eliminar al usuario?",
      text: "Elija una opcion",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/evaluacion/concerderRsol/" + nombreEva + "/" + id,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html"
        }).done(function(data){
            swal("si!", "bien", "success");
        });
      }
    }); //<- hacía falta
});
```